# Rotating an object around a tilted axis

Tags: math, 3d, rotation, pseudocode

I have the coordinates of a centre point . I also have an array called the asteroid normal which I assume is the relative rotation of the axis (its 3 numbers between zero and one).

How can I make an object revolve around this object? I haven't been able to find any formula that does this.

Comment: Basically you need to transform the object to 0,0,0 so it's axis aligned, rotate it there then apply the inverse of the first transform.

Comment: @ChrisF Can you be a little more specific? I can move the object but there are no builtin rotating functions. It's orientation doesn't matter as well , all I need is for it to rotate around the titlted axis at 4deg/s at a distance of 0.3.

Comment: You have to generate the transformation matrices yourself. It's been a while since I did this sort of thing for a living so don't have examples to hand.

Comment: @ChrisF I don't need examples , the theory would do. How do I generate the matrix , I only have those 2 arrays. There are vector function but I'm not quite sure what to do with them. I know how to do revolving in 2d but can't work it out for 3d.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslate(-x,-y,-z);
glRotate(angle,nx,ny,nz);
glTranslate(x,y,z);
```

Comment: Thanks , but the opengl tag was an accident. Is it possible to calculate the point position rather than using rotate functions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [rotation matrix for an axis and angle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) The new position `p'` of a point `p` on the object is

```
p' = center + R(angle, axis) * (p - center)
```

where `R(angle, axis)` is the matrix that rotates by `angle` about `axis`, and `center` is a point that the axis passes through. Tal Darom's answer is the same, only in OpenGL notation.